# How to extract object from image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a dataset with a person wearing HMD. I want to create a mask for the HMD. Here is an example :

[image]

I need to create a mask for the FOVE headset. I have tried semantic segmentation models. They are able to create silhouette of the person as a whole but not the HMD separately. It makes sense as FOVE is not a class in their model. I can't retrain the model with FOVE examples as I dont have any mask data to train on. So I turned to Image Processing methods. I have tried clustering approach for segmentation and have tried MeanShift algorithm, KMeans algorithm, thresholding of images and graphcut algorithm.

Here are problems I faced with each :

1. Mean-Shift Clustering: It creates a lot of classes (>1000). I need to be able to extract the FOVE class without manual intervention as I need to process a lot of data (>2000 images). I smoothed my input image that decreased the number of classes but it also created separate classes within FOVE HMD caused by a different luminosity gradient. Also, a lot of images have similar background, just like in example. Mean Shift is confused in those cases.

[image: MeanShift Output]

2. KMeans : Low quality output. It gets confused and is inaccurate. Given output is for k=10.

[image: KMeans Output]

3. Thresholding of Image : It is able to create a good outline of Fove, but I don't know how to extract the HMD coordinates using that. The output is with adaptive thresholding.

[image: Adaptive Thresholding output]

4. GrabCut : Not good output and needs manual intervention.
   Edit : The GrabCut algorithm needs to have as input a bounding box that is very close to the face. With 2000 images that need this preprocessing, I am unable to do this manually. With a general & larger bounding box, accuracy decreases. I would like to try some method that doesn't require manual input, if possible, first.

[image: GrabCut Output]

Please suggest what I can do to create mask for HMD.

EDIT: 
Here's what I am using now. The most troublesome part was the background, which in my dataset was sometimes just a few values less white than FOVE and sometimes wildly different. I trained a semantic segmentation network to detect and extract the person from the image. For reference, [this](https://github.com/torrvision/crfasrnn) and [this](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) are some of the good work that has been done on this subject. After that, I used mean shift algorithm in order to get clusters and performed color thresholding on the image. This gave me ~90% accuracy, and rest of images needed some tweaking(mostly on color thresholding).

[image: Mask from semantic segmentation]

[image: Final Mask being created]

Comment: Seems - if I have understood your problem correctly - that you are almost there with CrabCut. So CrabCut + HSV-filtering/tresholding and/or adaptive tresholding.

Comment: if your input image is always like this, with a person and hmd and almost plain background, then you can use hough transform or contours to detect rectangle in the image

Comment: @Mika72 The GrabCut algorithm needs to have as input a bounding box that is very close to the face. With 2000 images that need this preprocessing, I am unable to do this manually. With a general & larger bounding box, accuracy decreases. I would like to try some method that doesn't require manual input, if possible, first.

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari Its not rectangle, but curved on corners. I need a very sharp silhouette of the HMD. Is it possible to do so with contours? I haven't tried them yet.

Comment: You can get curved contours as output of cv2.contours, but it will not be a perfect contour for HMD. you need to do some preprocessing